# RANK data by value in the column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to divide the data into separate groups (chunks) based on the value in the column. If the value increase above certain threshold, the value in the "group" should increase by 1.

This would be easy to achieve in MySQL, by doing `CASE WHEN @val > 30 THEN @row_no + 1 ELSE @row_no END` however I am using Amazon Redshift where this is not allowed.

Sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00b3aa/6

Suggested output:

| ID | Value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 22 | 1 |
| 4 | 11 | 1 |
| 5 | 35 | 2 |
| 6 | 11 | 2 |
| 7 | 11 | 2 |
| 8 | 11 | 2 |
| 9 | 66 | 3 |
| 10 | 11 | 3 |

Comment: What about [NTILE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-ntile-function/) function?

Comment: NTILE woudln't work, as in my case one group can have millions of row, another one just a few. And it's redshift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cumulative sum should do what you want:

```
SELECT *, sum((val>=30)::INTEGER) OVER (ORDER BY id BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM mydata ORDER BY id;
 id | val | sum
----+-----+-----
  1 |  11 |   0
  2 |  11 |   0
  3 |  22 |   0
  4 |  11 |   0
  5 |  35 |   1
  6 |  11 |   1
  7 |  11 |   1
  8 |  11 |   1
  9 |  66 |   2
 10 |  11 |   2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, howeverI had to add the frame clause

Comment: @Petrik . . . If you want the values to start at one, just include `+ 1`.